# Testlink: Export complete test cases into OpenOffice

Tags: openoffice.org, testlink

I have a large number of test cases in Testlink and I need to export them into either OpenOffice Calc or Writer (and then possibly reimport them), including test steps.

Currently Testlink only supports XML for exports and imports of test cases. To import an XML file into OpenOffice and export it, specifically formatted XSLT files are needed. To create them appears to be rather time consuming if you are not an XML expert.

Did anybody do this already? Does anybody have examples or working XSLT files for Testlink test cases, for Calc or Writer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My bad. It turns out that it is very easily possible to export test cases *with* test steps:

1. Choose **Test Reports** in the topmost menu of Testlink.
2. On the Reports and Metrics page, select **OpenOffice Writer** (or MS Word) as the Report Format.
3. On the left side, select **Test Plan Report**. On the right side, select the checkbox **Test Scenario** (you don't need Test Summary or any other options). Below, click on the test case folder that you wish to export.
4. You get the document for download. (Note: may require some formatting.)

Alternatively, it is possible to choose HTML in step 2 as the report format and save the frame.

While it is possible to select OpenOffice Calc/MS Excel, there doesn't seem to be a way to include test case steps.

Comment: My experience when running 1.9.15 is that the exported xml schema is unintelligible for consumption without pre-parsing. And that the document form reports are containing so much whitespace that I have 50 pages of text, not really manager-friendly, so be warned, mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the test report subjects?

1. Choose *Test Reports* in the topmost menu of *Testlink*.
2. On the Reports and Metrics page, select *OpenOffice* Writer (or MS Word) as the Report Format.
3. On the left side, select *Test Plan Report*. On the right side, select the *checkbox Test Scenario* (you don't need Test Summary or
   any other options). Below, click on the test case folder that you wish to export.
4. You get the document for download.

Can i change the download file name?

When i choose the testcase folder, i can download the test report(MS word). but file name is "Test Project name.doc". so I want to change the file name **from "Test project name" to "Test Plan name"**